# Slideshow with image paths from an XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, slideshow

i tried so many slideshows that i found online that im done with them. The task should be easy, but since im a jquery newbie it beats me:

XML, JQUERY or Javascript should be used

I want to create a slideshow, for which i have the pictures in a IMAGES folder and all i want to do is write the paths of these images in an XML file and read it from there, something like this:

```
<allImages>
 <oneImage>
 Image/picture1.jpg
 </oneImage>
 <oneImage>
 Image/picture2.jpg
 </oneImage>
 <oneImage>
 Image/picture3.jpg
 </oneImage>
 <oneImage>
 Image/picture4.jpg
 </oneImage>
</allImages>
```

Nothing fancy, just a slideshow that repeats on and on the pictures whose paths are found in an XML file. This should be done with jQUERY OR Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a JSON instead of XML. JSON is simple and faster than XML

```
// JSON Object
var imagesJSON = [
  "Image/picture1.jpg",
  "Image/picture2.jpg",
  "Image/picture3.jpg",
  "Image/picture4.jpg"];

$(function() {
    LoopThroughImages();
});

var i=0;
function LoopThroughImages(){
    var imgPath = imagesJSON[i]; // Write the code for reading the image path from XML here
    $("#image").attr('src',imgPath  );
    i++;
    if(i >= 4)
        i=0;
    setTimeout(LoopThroughImages, 3000);
}
```

You can see a sample code in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gvjkf/1/)